# Beamer Article package, overlay not working

Tags: beamer, overlays, beamerarticle

I am trying to create a document using the `beamerarticle` package in LaTeX. I am unable to use overlays. A MWE is appended.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\title[T]{T} 
\author{A}
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage

\begin{frame}{Overview}

\only<1->{Trial}

\only<2->{Trial}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

In this case, both blocks of text "trial" appear at the same time. An overlay is not created.

Please suggest how I can use overlays with `beamerarticle`.